# Разделить строку и кавычки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

У меня есть строка, например `" \" HELLO FRIEND \" "`

Мне нужно разделить её методом split(), в данном случае, на 4 части.

В итоге должен получиться массив `{", HELLO, FRIEND, "}`

Comment: Что у Вас не получилось при применении этой функции?

Comment: Не получилось именно разделить слова и кавычки т.е я не знаю правильного рег. выражения, которое выдаст именно то, что я указал в вопросе

Comment: @Jiftoo Вам нужно JSON на выходе?

Comment: @Tsyklop нет, мне нужен просто обычный массив строк

Comment: @Jiftoo не пойму зачем кавычки в примере результата. зачем они?

Comment: @Tsyklop В них смысл задачи - разделить строку в которой содержатся кавычки, игнорируя пробелы

Comment: `.trim().split(" ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут можно обойтись без RegExp'ов. Передай пробел аргументом в функцию split, а потом отфильтруй результат, что бы в массиве не было пустых строк:

```
" \" HELLO FRIEND \" ".split(' ').filter(str=>str!='');
```